# Can I change a public member from parent class to private in derived class in C#?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a class DraggableBorder derived from Border but I wanna make Border.Child private.
How can I do it?

Comment: What exactly do you need that for?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It would break [Liskov's Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). If `DraggableBorder` derives from `Border`, I would expect to be able to use it as if it were a `Border`.

After all, someone could always write:

```
Border border = new DraggableBorder();
border.Child = ...;
```

How would you expect the compiler to stop that?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the original Child by defining a new private member

```
public class DraggableBorder : Border
{
    private new object Child {get;set;}
}
```

This way the compiler prevents you from accessing the original child property

```
DraggableBorder myBorder = ...;
myBorder.Child ; // this will result in a compiler error
```

however this is no real protection because you can easily work around it

```
((Border)myBorder).Child; // this will be ok
Border myBaseBorder = myBorder;
myBaseBorder.Child; // this will be ok
```